# Using C++11 std::thread native_handle and whether I need to CloseHandle

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++11

I'm starting to get into the practice of using C++11 `std::thread`s.  Typically, with Win32, I need to call `CloseHandle` whenever I have a handle to a thread.  Do I still need to call `CloseHandle` when I use a C++11 `native_handle`?  Also, if I don't use C++11 native handles, do thread handles get cleaned up properly?

Comment: [RAII says no extra cleanup required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) If you have a standard library class portable across many platforms and you have to perform additional platform-specific voodoo, your standard library's portability is shot.

Answer (score 3):

Of course not. 
Thread Objects has a destructor which releases any operating system specific resources that the object may acquired.

Actually, every (good) C++ object has a destructor which cleans whatever is needed to be cleaned up and this destructor (when the code is written correctly) **is** called automatically by the program.

this idiom is known as RAII - every object has a constructor which gathers resources that the object needs, and a peer destructor which releases them when the object gets out of scope.

when done correctly, this technique is far more powerfull than C-style manual resource management or a "high-level" garbage collector.

as a word of advise, if the standard provides you with some utility, ignore completely the corresponding Win32 API. the standard **does not** depends on an operating system specific API to work correctly.

Comment: [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203/). A destructor *is* a garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  That's probably a good practice.  While my app is only intended for use on Win32, I'd like to get in the practice of using the standard library over things like `WaitForSingleObject` such as waiting for threads to join, or using `std::condition_variable` instead of Win32 events. I unfortunately don't have enough karma to upvote your post.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are RAII, like shared pointers. 
Main thing you  need to worry about are:

- synchronization (no pain no gain!)
- that you cannot copy threads (deleted constructor) so you pass them by reference.

Details here.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/